What kind of visa is necessary for transiting Turkey by land?
Turkey offers a transit e-visa, which is easy to obtain, but only allows the person to stay within the airport.
What kind of visa is neccessary for someone, who wants to fly to Istanbul and take a bus to another country (transit by land)?
Source: https://turkey-e-visas.com/news/turkey-transit-visa-for-nepalese-citizens/
Passport: Nepal, Residency: Dubai

It's always useful to specify your nationality, passports held, citizenship, residency, etc, when asking a question like this, as well as the reason for your travel (tourism, study, etc), your onward destination, and any other visas held/to be used on your journey. Holding a Schengen or some other visas can also entitle you to an e-Visa: see.

While the Turkish government publishes eligibility criteria for eVisas, your eligibility is determined by the name of the country which issued your passport or other travel document. If you are not eligible for an eVisa, you must apply (at or through a Turkish embassy or consulate) for a regular visa. Please amend your question (using the "Edit" button below the question text) to add this info.

As an adjacent note: You almost definitely don't want to do this. It's likely to be slower and more expensive than flying. I considered this option for trains before and it sadly sucks.

Passport: Nepal, residecncy Dubai

@ave I can't speak for the OP but I sometimes choose a slower, tougher land route deliberately.  A land trip can be a fun adventure.  Flights are usually dull.  Long ago, I crossed Turkey by land and loved it.

@DavidRecallsMonica what kind of visa?

Travel.SE expects participants to try to answer their own questions. Read the Travel.SE Help page to find how this site work. Thus, take your information (Nepali passport) and read the Turkish government webpage I cited in my earlier comment. I suspect you'll find information on the Turkish eVisa page about what kind of entry an eVisa may be used for, and what kind of entry requires a conventional visa application at a Turkish embassy or consulate...

...Then, if you cannot find the information you seek, come back and report on what you did find, and what you still want to know.

@DavidRecallsMonica your smug self congratulatory comment is completely out of place. Since you haven't even properly read the question, you shouldn't lecture others on doing their homework. Still its confusing, what exactly you had an issue with understanding? You suspect I will find info on the turkish e-visa page? Same one I linked and cited? I asked what kind of visa is necessary for what I want to do. No, there isn't a land transit visa, otherwise this question would be unnecessary. Transiting by car is also not really tourism. Starting to understand where the problem is?

You already have the information you need.
You said in your question that a Turkish eVisa only allows a traveler to stay within the airport. Even if you arrive by air, you do not want to stay within the airport because you want to travel overland to exit Turkey over a land border.
You cannot do that using a Turkish eVisa. The only conclusion possible is that you must apply for and receive a conventional entry visa issued by a Turkish embassy or consulate.

According to the question, a "transit e-visa" is only valid for airport transit.  But Turkey offers other classes of visa as e-visas, at least for certain nationalities.  I don't have time just now to check the requirements for Nepalese citizens, but it's certainly possible that a "tourist e-visa" is available that would meet this traveler's needs without the need to apply at an embassy or consulate.

@phoog I agree, it certainly could be so. As noted earlier, the OP should read the Turkish government eVisa webpage as it applies to Nepali citizens.

But what is a conventional visa? 90 days tourist visa? But the purpose isn't really tourism.

@user1721135 Traveling across Turkey by land could be seen as tourism, although you explain it's also a transit. OTOH, as shown in the answer, you do not qualify for an eVisa. You need a visa issued by the Turkish consulate or embassy, of sufficient duration to encompass your planned stay in Turkey.

@user1721135 that's why you need to do your research, by consulting an official Turkish source (government website, consulate, embassy). For MANY countries whether it'd be a tourist visa, business visa, or transit visa would depend on the reason for the trip as well as the duration (4 hours on a train might be transit, 10 days by bus or taxi probably not, for example).

@jwenting I did consult an official source, which is linked and cited in the question and it is not helpful. In many countries there is a transit visa, which does not limit you to the airport transit, so you can for example transit by car. But not Turkey.

This is a partial answer to the OP's question about the suitability of a Turkish eVisa for their intended trip to Turkey by air, then across Turkey by land, then exiting Turkey though a land crossing into another country.
TL;dr
While the OP can apply online for a Turkish eVisa, the OP does not meet all the eVisa requirements and their application for an eVisa will be denied.
Instead, the OP will need a regular visa issued by a Turkish Embassy or Consulate
The Whole Explanation
The Turkish government's opening page for Turkish eVisas (also cited in my comment to the OP's question) notes that Nepali citizens are eligible to apply for Turkish eVisas.
However, more hurdles exist. Continuing the eVisa application process brings up this page, which lists additional specific requirements for issuance and use of the eVisa. The chart below appears on this page, and lists these additional requirements next to a column of check boxes:

The first box requires the applicant to hold a return ticket, a hotel reservation, and at least $50 (currency not further specified) per day for each day of stay in Turkey. Here, however, the OP plans to transit Turkey by bus and leave overland. The OP will not have a return ticket, and therefore does not meet all the requirements listed in the first box. The OP cannot check this box.
The second box requires the applicant to have a Supporting Document, defined as a visa or residence permit from a Schengen country, USA, UK, or Ireland. The OP may be able to meet this requirement, but insufficient information is revealed in the question to know if the OP can meet this second box requirements.
The third box requires the OP to have a passport valid for at least 6 months from the date they intend to enter Turkey. The OP may be able to meet this requirement, but insufficient information is revealed in the question to know if the OP can meet this second box requirements.
The fourth box indicates the applicant will travel to Turkey by air. The OP meets this requirement, and can check the fourth box.
The fifth box requires the OP to affirm they meet every requirement listed at boxes 1 through 4. Because the OP cannot show a return ticket — one of the requirements listed in Box 1 — the OP does not meet every requirement listed on this form, and cannot check the fifth box.
Summary: the OP cannot check the first and fifth boxes, and may be unable to check the second and third boxes. Because the OP cannot check all five boxes, they are not eligible for a Turkish eVisa for this journey.

In this case I could in fact show a return ticket, since I would be landing in Turkey and continuing by car and coming back the same way.

@user1721135 In your original question, you said "What kind of visa is neccessary for someone, who wants to fly to Istanbul and take a bus to another country (transit by land)?" You didn't say you would re-enter Turkey, and didn't say you would leave Turkey by air. You're now changing your itinerary. Still, you would be unable to say you would "remain in the airport" (one of the first conditions on the preliminary Turkish government eVisa site). If you find my reading the actual Turkish government info "smug and self-congratulatory" I invite you to ignore me. This will be my last comment here.
